# How to override a function using server script ERPNext v14

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I need to override the function that calculate the amount in the quotation item quantity * rate by quantity * rate * length * width knowing i had changed in the client side but when saving the quotation it returns to the original formula I tried the two following script but I can’t seem to access the field. anyone got any ideas ? thank you in advance.
I’m using doctype event:

```
amount = flt(doc.quantity) * flt(doc.rate) * flt(doc.length) * flt(doc.width)
frappe.db.set_value("Quotation Item", doc.name, "amount", amount)
print("Script is working")
```

and the second one:

```
def before_save(doc, event):
    doc.amount = doc.quantity * doc.rate * doc.length * doc.width
    print("Script is working")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if some other method is getting called after the before_save method.
Please share some more details. Maybe I can help you here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the answer apparently you should create a custom app and merge it with you ERPNext app and then create a file in the hooks.py directory this is code inside it
your_custom_file.py:

```
import frappe
from frappe.utils import flt

def update_item_amount(doc, method):
    for item in doc.items:
        item.amount = flt(item.qty) * flt(item.rate) * flt(item.length) * flt(item.width)
        frappe.db.set_value('Quotation Item', item.name, 'amount', item.amount)
```

and as for the hooks.py:

```
doc_events = {
"Quotation": {
    "before_save": "your_app_name.your_custom_file.update_item_amount"
}}
```

it is working but I need to optimize it more hope it helps